# Прошлогодний шляпный заголовок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, новогодние-шляпы

В заголовке окна написано

> WINTER BASH 2018

Очевидно, что должно быть или 2019, или 2020, но точно не 2018.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: нарядился так что я испугался а у меня сердце слабое ...